# Is there already a program that analyzes THz-TDS data in Mathematica?

Tags: import, complex, physics, numerical-value

I plan to write a code that reads the time domain data(sample+reference), performs Fourier transforms, calculates transmissivity, solves the transfer function numerically, and gets complex refractive index and optical conductivity, does average, etc.
Since the THz time-domain spectroscopy (THz-TDS) technique is widely spread, I wonder maybe there is already a public code written in Mathematica that I can use as a start. I searched but I did not find any.  I know that in MATLAB, there are solutions, but  I like how Mathematica can handle complex-valued functions, so I would like to use it to analyze my data. I am a new user of this language.
Any ideas, links are welcome!